# table contents has no column named

Tags: android, sqlite

After adding a new column in a table, I get the error:

> table contents has no column named "cname"

The "cname" is on a different table from the last column I added.

What I have tried so far:

1. Clean - rebuild project.
2. Delete app from phone and reinstall, done this multiple times.
3. Export database from phone to check if the column is in database - it was.

Any other ideas?

Comment: did you try Clearing Data from App info?

Comment: @TouhidulIslam I uninstall the app so I guess all data deleted

Comment: Post the code of your SQLiteOpenHelper class and the code that throws this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any case someone has the same problem, I believe that there was something wrong with the SQLiteStudio program I used to insert the new fields to the database. I removed them and added them again and everything works perfect.